# Migration from geolocation to geofield

Tags: nodes, database

**Problem**:
My contenttype has a geolocation field and I added more than 600 contents of that contenttype with geolocation lat-lon. Now I added a new geofield field in that same contenttype and I want to transfer all geolocation field (only points) values into this newly created geofield.

**Tried solutions with no success**:
1. ran following insert and update queries:

```
INSERT INTO `field_revision_field_geofield_field` (
    `entity_type`,
    `bundle`,
    `deleted`,
    `entity_id`,
    `revision_id`,
    `language`,
    `delta`,
    `field_geofield_field_lat`,
    `field_geofield_field_lon`,
    `field_geofield_field_left`,
    `field_geofield_field_top`,
    `field_geofield_field_right`,
    `field_geofield_field_bottom`,
    `field_geofield_field_geohash`
)
SELECT
    `entity_type`,
    `bundle`,
    `deleted`,
    `entity_id`,
    `revision_id`,
    `language`,
    `delta`,
    `field_geolocation_field_lat`,
    `field_geolocation_field_lng`,
    `field_geolocation_field_lng`,
    `field_geolocation_field_lat`,
    `field_geolocation_field_lng`,
    `field_geolocation_field_lat`,
    null
FROM `field_revision_field_geolocation_field`

UPDATE `field_revision_field_geofield_field`
SET `field_geofield_field_geo_type`="point"
```

But still geofield values are not appearing in my content display.

How to go about this issue?

**Note**: I inserted and updated field_data_field_geofield_field also as it is the one which is needed to reflect in the page. However the fields are not getting displayed. Work around I found is to edit the content (the geofield lat/lon are filled) and clicking save puts values into 'geom' and 'geohash' fields after which geofield values are displayed in my display and views.

However doing the above operation for each content is so laborious. Looking for bulk trigger save option (VBO is very close, still it does not trigger save of geofield for an unknown reason). I hope it is a separate issue.

Comment: I inserted and updated field_data_field_geofield_field also as it is the one which is needed to reflect in the page. However the fields are not getting displayed. Work around I found is to edit the content (the geofield lat/lon are filled) and clicking save puts values into 'geom' and 'geohash' fields after which geofield values are displayed in my display and views.

Comment: My problem now is to trigger that save in bulk mode. Tried using VBO but no use. It does not trigger to save 'geom' and 'geohash' fields of geofield. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not do direct database manipulation, instead you should edit each node programmatically, port values from geolocation field to geofield field and save node.

Comment: @sanzante, please elaborate it. How do I do it in drupal?